# D3JS selection selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this piece of code :

```
var series, seriesChildren;

selection.each(function (data) {
    series = d3.select(this).selectAll('.my-series').data([data]);
    series.enter().append('g').classed('my-series', true);

    console.log(data);
    seriesChildren = series.selectAll('.seriesChild')
            .data(data, function (d) {
                return d.x;
            });

    seriesChildren.enter()
            .append('g')
            .classed('seriesChild', true);
}
```

And I don't understand why it gives me the following :

```
<g class="my-series"></g>
```

without the children.

It should be :

```
<g class="my-series">
  <g class="seriesChild"></g>
  <g class="seriesChild"></g>
  ...
</g>
```

I did a `console.log(data)` and my data is good, it has thousands of elements within it.

It is working by doing `seriesChildren = d3.selectAll('.my-series').selectAll('.seriesChild')` but not working with `seriesChildren = series.selectAll('.seriesChild')`

I'm using D3JS v4.

Comment: The data method for the nested selection doesn't seem to be right. You have to share the structure of your data array (not all of it, just a couple of elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two statements are diffrent
`1. seriesChildren = series.selectAll('.seriesChild')`

`2. seriesChildren = d3.selectAll('.my-series').selectAll('.seriesChild')`

In 1st series is not a DOM element hence `seriesChildren = d3.selectAll('.my-series').selectAll('.seriesChild')` will not work as you are expecting

whereas in second case `d3.selectAll('.my-series')` this represent a DOM element and furter `d3.selectAll('.myseries').selectAll('.seriesChild')` will select another DOM element.